# How can I add dynamic height adjustments for text-areas in Streamlit?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, streamlit

In my scenario i have two st.columns with two textareas. One is for User-Input the other one is for generated text.

Is it possible to expand the textarea with every line and get rid of the scroll bar in the text area?

While testing I was only able to use the scrollbar and I know that you are able to use st.markdown to insert HTML, but I don't know how to call the textareas and how to edit these to adjust the height dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a small script which will do the work. Checkout this

```js
const textArea = document.querySelector('.textarea-test')

textArea.addEventListener('input',(e)=>{
textArea.style.height = "auto"
  textArea.style.height = `${textArea.scrollHeight}px`;
})
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="4" class="textarea-test"></textarea>
```

Comment: I've tried this, but sadly it still doesn't work. (See other comment)

Answer (score 1):

```
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as v1

st.set_page_config(page_title="Test Site", layout="wide")


col1, col2 = st.columns(2)

with col1:
    userInput = st.text_area("Input:")

with col2:
    generatedText = st.text_area("Output:", key="Output")


#Testbox
html_string='''
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="4" class="textarea-test"></textarea>
    <script>
        const textArea = document.querySelector(".textarea-test")

        textArea.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
            textArea.style.height = "auto"
            textArea.style.height = `${textArea.scrollHeight}px`;
        })
    </script>
'''

v1.html(html_string)
```

The testbox is now working. The problem now is to identify the two textareas created by streamlit inside of the columns above. The document known to the script does not know these two textareas. Therefore selection by query selector is not possible.